# ramda js updating deeply nested arrays in second and third level

Tags: ramda.js, lenses

```
const items ={
  "costList":[
     {
       "cost": [10, 20],
       "order":20
     } ,
    {
      "cost": [20, 30],
      "order":20
    }
  ],
  "testObject3":[{
    "testArray":[
      {
        testInnerArray:[10,20,30,40],
        testNumber:30
      },
     {
        testInnerArray:[10,20,30,40],
        testNumber:30
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to use ramda and update the array that is either 2 levels or 3 levels down in the json document.

a. For the first one i am trying to update cost array and multiply by a factor.
I used the following ramda function and it is giving me Nan as the value, where as i was expecting [20,40] in the case of the first and [40, 60] in the case of second array index.
I used the following ramda statement for transformation:

```
const costListLens = R.lensProp('costList');

const costLens = R.lensProp('cost');

var convertedData = R.over(costListLens, R.map(R.over(costLens, R.multiply(2))
                                                          ))(items);
```

b. In the case of second case, I am trying to update the array that is 3 levels down.

---

```
const firstLevelLens = R.lensProp('testObject3');
const secondLevelLens = R.lensProp('testArray');
const thirdLevelLens = R.lensProp('testInnerArray');
R.over(firstLevelLens, R.map(R.over(secondLevelLens, R.map(R.over(thirdLevelLens, R.multiply(2))                                                         ))))(items)*
```

---

In both the cases the array is being set to Nan. Can you please suggest what is the error?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing some `map` statements.  Your lenses get at properties; however those are not objects but arrays.  You (presumably) want to work with the elements of the arrays.  So you need `map` statements interspersed:

```js
const {lensProp, over, map, multiply} = R

const items ={"costList": [{"cost": [10, 20], "order": 20}, {"cost": [20, 30], "order": 20}], "testObject3": [{"testArray": [{"testInnerArray": [10, 20, 30, 40], "testNumber": 30}, {"testInnerArray": [10, 20, 30, 40], "testNumber": 30}]}]}

const costListLens = lensProp('costList')
const costLens = lensProp('cost')

const updateCosts = over(costListLens, map(over(costLens, map(multiply(2)))))

console.log(updateCosts(items))

const firstLevelLens = lensProp('testObject3')
const secondLevelLens = lensProp('testArray')
const thirdLevelLens = lensProp('testInnerArray')

const updateInner = over(
  firstLevelLens, 
  map(over(secondLevelLens, map(over(thirdLevelLens, map(multiply(2))))))
)

console.log(updateInner(items))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Note, though that if you had a structure like this, without the array, that lenses compose:

```js
const {lensProp, over, compose, map, multiply} = R

const costListLens = lensProp('costList')
const costLens = lensProp('cost')

const simplerItems = {
  costList: {
    cost: [10, 20],
    order: 20
  }
}

const updateSimplerCosts = over(
  compose(costListLens, costLens), 
  map(multiply(2))
)

console.log(updateSimplerCosts(simplerItems))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

And you could similarly `compose` multiple lenses.  Note that the order of composition seems backward.  That's just how it works, although there are plenty of references to explain why if you search for `lens+compose+backward`.

Comment: You are awesome!! thank you so much for the clarifications!!